# Why the result not equivalent with original image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-manipulation

If I use this command in MATLAB, the image is distorted and is not retained. Why is this so?

```
>> b = imread('eight.tif');
>> b2 = imdivide(b,64);
>> bb2 = immultiply(b2,64);
>> imshow(bb2)
>> imshow(b);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, works fine over here (save for some obvious color changes)...Can you upload your figure somehow?

Comment: what do you mean by "distorted"?

Comment: What if `b` is `uint8` array? I think that for all elements of `b` smaller that 64 corresponding `b2` elements will be zeros and so will be `bb2` elements due to integer arithmetics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you dividing a uint8 image. When you divide your image (which has a range of values between 0 and 255) by 64 you will end up with an image with values 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. When you multiply it back, you will get 0, 64, 128, 192, and 255, instead of the full range of values you initially had.

Check this out: `imshow(b/64*64)`. THis will show you the same artifact.

Now check this: `imshow(uint8(double(b)/64*64))`. This will show you the original image. You are able to recover the values in this case because the operations are performed on doubles rather than uint8.

Comment: Btw, you can use `unique(b(:))`. This will list all the unique values in the `b` matrix, and it can help you inspect what changed.

Answer (score 3):

You are performing operations on pixels of image stored as `uint8` (unsigned 8-bits).
Dividing the pixels by 64 you basically shift-right the values by 6 (!) bits, that is, you leave only 2 (1) most significant bits per-pixel. Multiplying back by 64 fills the 6 least-significant-bits with zeros - **data is lost**.

---

Here's a little example:

```
>> a = uint8(153); dec2bin(a)
ans =
 0b10011001
>> b = a/64;       dec2bin(b)
ans =
 0b00000010
```

Note how all the 6 bits on the right ( `011001` ) are GONE! only the two bits from the left (`10`) are remained (shifted to the right). This division operation caused you **loss of data**.
Now, multiplying back:

```
>> c = b*64;       dec2bin(c)
ans =
 0b10000000
```

All the 6 bits on the right are now `0`! the previous values `011001` are GONE!

---

Another exampe by [Rody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085062/rody-oldenhuis):

```
data = uint8(1:255);

figure(1), clf, hold on

plot(data, data, 'b')
plot(data, data/uint8(64)*uint8(64), 'r')

xlabel('Original Values')
ylabel('Ouptut values')

axis tight
legend('Original color space', 'Color space after integer division/multiply',...
    'Location', 'NorthWest')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I figured something lke this would be going on, but he said "distorted" so I thought the shapes, sizes and/or ratios changed...Well, +1 for you anyway :)

Comment: I didn't get it. Can i hava an explanation in Layman terms please ?

Comment: @user75736 what exactly don't you understand? are you familiar with `uint8` data type?